# How to make cursor to be same size as text inside EditText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

How to make cursor to be same size as text inside `EditText`? I have `EditText` like this, but I cannot make cursor to be the same as text (font has size 48`px`, has to be in `px`, not `dp`).

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    style="@style/txt"
    android:layout_width="310px"
    android:layout_height="110px"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
    android:fontFamily="segoe.ttf"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:paddingBottom="10px"
    android:paddingTop="10px"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the cursor to be the same size as text you can use the following attribute for your `EditText`:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
```

where `cursor.xml` is located in `res/drawable' folder and defined as follows:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
<size 
    android:width="2px" />
<solid
    android:color="#ff0000" />
<padding 
    android:top="-15px"
    android:bottom="-13px" />
</shape>
```

I adjusted `top` and `bottom` attributes to be the same size as digits (font 48px). If you're not going to use only numeric values, change the attribute's values a bit.